# AssertionError caused by pyinstaller when creating an executable

Tags: python-2.7, inno-setup, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a .exe file from a .pyw python file using PyInstaller. 
I am using the command `pyinstaller --onefile sysTray.pyw` but I am always getting an `AssertionError` I read around to try and debug the error but couldn't arrive at a conclusion. These are the last few lines before the error.

```
File "c:\users\elkha\anaconda2-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 370, in add
code = get_code_object(nm, pathnm)
File "c:\users\elkha\anaconda2-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 545, in get_code_object
co = _load_code(modname, filename)
File "c:\users\elkha\anaconda2-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 521, in _load_code
assert loader and hasattr(loader, 'get_code')
AssertionError
```

My ultimate goal is to then use innosetup to create an installer for the application. I was using py2exe before the complete this task but I also ran into problems so I decided to switch to pyinstaller but it seems that there are issues with pyinstaller as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

I have Anaconda Python 2.7 (32-bit) and I installed PyInstaller 3.2 from their [website](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Comment: If I remember correctly (I can't find the link), there are some issues with Anaconda and PyInstaller 3.2. I think that these get solved at the latest development version. Try [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#getting-the-latest-version) minus the `-e` option.

Comment: I will try that today, thank you @Repiklis.